# Not finding Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps NuGet package

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package, maui

I installed latest visual studio preview (Visual Studio Community 2022 Preview - 17.4.0 Preview 3) with .NET 7 include. I started a new project to experience the new Map control and selected the target .NET to be net7.0. Now when searching for the NuGet package Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps I'm unable to find it in the NuGet solution. How and where can I install it?

Comment: vs preview latest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maps is only available as a pre-release at the moment of writing: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps

You need to tick the check box that says **Include prerelease** when you search for NuGets in the Package Manager.

Comment: I am still not able to see it in the package manager after ticking the 'Include prerelease' checkbox.

Comment: @PoorneshV Make sure the correct package source is selected. At the time of writing, the package already has officially released versions (v. 8.0.6).